# Do having a method that process both GET and POST requests violates SRP?

Tags: solid, single-responsibility

I'm starting with Zend Framework 3 and I saw an example on the tutorial that goes like this:

```
public function addAction()
{
    $form = new AlbumForm();
    $form->get('submit')->setValue('Add');

    $request = $this->getRequest();

    if (! $request->isPost()) {       // <-------------- HERE!!!!
        return ['form' => $form];
    }

    $album = new Album();
    $form->setInputFilter($album->getInputFilter());
    $form->setData($request->getPost());

    if (! $form->isValid()) {
        return ['form' => $form];
    }

    $album->exchangeArray($form->getData());
    $this->table->saveAlbum($album);
    return $this->redirect()->toRoute('album');
}
```

Now, considering what Robert C. Martin says about SRP (from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle#Example)):

> A class or module should have one, and only one, reason to change.

From my perspective, given the specifications for the creation form changes  (maybe we now have to load data in a dropdown box) this would affect the GET request. However, given the specification for a redirection changes (we now redirect to `/index` instead of `/details`) this would affect the POST request.

Since both are in the same method, does this violates SRP, or am I missing something?

**Disclaimer:** I come from Laravel, where we have 1 method for each request; so having a check like `if($request->isPost) {}` feels wrong. But this is official Zend Framework 3 documentation, so maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: SRP doesn't mean "Do one thing."  It means "Have one concern." (as in "separation of concerns")

Comment: @RobertHarvey could you expand a little bit more please?

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco A method or a class can do many things, as long as those things are on the same level of abstraction for the same concept, it respects the SRP. For example, you could manage authentication of users with high level validation, along with high level error returning (with business rules ie 6 letters min for password), and then validation could be done at a lower level with database (does user and password match in DB). As you can see, validating everything in the same method would be a bad choice here because the levels of abstraction would be merged, thus violate SRP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding, but it seems there are two questions here: one about HTTP endpoint design, and another about function design.

### Endpoints

I am not familiar with PHP, nor the Zend Framework. But in designing a REST(ish) API, it is quite common to have an endpoint `api.mysite/users` representing a collection (in this case of users). A `GET` to said endpoint would return a collection of all the users, and a `POST` to the endpoint would create a new user.

I cannot read your code, so I can't tell whether this is the case for you. But in general, different verbs on a single endpoint should be related.

### Functions

> I come from Laravel, where we have 1 method for each request; so having a check like if($request->isPost) {} feels wrong.

You're correct. In fact, a boolean-valued function `isPost` is wrong. The correct approach would be to have a method `getRequestMethod` that returns an enumeration - or in languages which lack such support, a string (*shudders*). The case statement would defer to the appropriate method. Of course, this logic could be taken care of behind the scenes, and then you would just fill in the appropriate `get`, `post`, functions etc (I use a framework that takes this approach).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, my concern isn't about REST API design. It's whether using the same object's method (method as in a Class method, **not http verb**) to handle both POST and GET requests violates SRP.  The example is meant to indicate that GET is handled outside of the `if-statement` where POST is handled inside it.

Comment: That means your method will 'Manage the route as GET protocol **and** as POST protocol'. This 'and' shows it breaks SRP. Also that means this method will change if the logic with either GET or POST protocol changes, which is another indication that it breaks SRP, it has more than one reason to change.

Comment: Oops, I meant to answer that. I updated my answer accordingly. No, one method should not handle both POST and GET.

Comment: The problem with saying no is that you then needs to show how it should be done.  Keep in mind that a posted form needs to be tested for validity and if the validity check fails the form needs to be shown with the incorrect data highlighted.  Doing this with two methods is awkward to say the least.  Here is a better example of why processing both get and post in one method is fine: http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#handling-form-submissions

Comment: I said how it should be done. There should be different functions for both POST and GET. I don't understand your example. If a user POSTs with incorrect data, then the response body should indicate such error. Servers can respond to both POST and GET requests.